# Materialize - How do I make a long vertical image stop overflowing inside a modal

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a long vertical image that overflows from a popup modal causing a scroll wheel to appear. I have already tried to use the  `responsive-img`class, but that does not stop the image from overflowing. The only way I can get it to stop is by setting a pixel limit, but that causes the image to look distorted and not responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image style like this:

```
img {
height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
object-fit: contain;}
```

It will now 100% height of its parent, in your case is a modal, and the width is responsive.

Feel free to change it to whatever value you see best.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that still does not solve my problem. I think I need to set a max height for the modal pop out but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yes, my code depends on modal size, set height for modal and it will be fine. To set height for your modal just define it in your CSS with the class or id of the modal.